# Error in Java while running 'xlsx' package in R for exporting data

Tags: java, r, xlsx

I am trying to export the data into excel using xlsx package.

Here is the code and error:

```
library('xlsx')
write.xlsx(data1, "data1.xlsx")

Error in .jcheck(silent = FALSE) : 
Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>.jcall(row[[ir]],   "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell;", "createCell", as.integer(colIndex[ic] - 1))<S4 object of class "jobjRef">
```

I have about 850,000 rows with 40 variables.Any suggestions for handling error would be helpful.

Comment: What's the structure of `data1`? Can you write smaller files? Can you create a minimal, [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: can you isolate the section of that file that is causing the problem? If so it will make it a lot easier for the package maintainer to debug the proble3.... and that is who you should have directed this question in the first place. There is a `maintainer` function.